# jquerymobile auto complete list not hidden

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery and trying to build an auto-complete feature for mobile versions. I am using the a filterable list with local data. When I load the page the list gets displayed on the page, rather than being hidden. Also the auto-complete functionality on the text box is not working. Following is my HTML snippet. I am using bootstrap with jquery
Also I have follwed the exmaple from the jquerymobile site 
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-autocomplete/

```js
Following is my HTML:

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <form id="searchForm" class="ui-filterable form-horizontal" role="form"  onsubmit="searchFormSubmit(); return false;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input data-type="search" class="form-control" id="search_city_id" name="search_city_id" placeholder="City." >
                 <ul class="ui-filterable" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#search_city_id">
                  <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Chrysler</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">GMC</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Infiniti</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Jeep</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Kia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mini</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Porsche</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Subaru</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Volkswagen</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
                 </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing the jquery mobile javascript file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

  <form id="searchForm" class="ui-filterable form-horizontal" role="form"  onsubmit="searchFormSubmit(); return false;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input data-type="search" class="form-control" id="search_city_id" name="search_city_id" placeholder="City." >
                 <ul class="ui-filterable" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#search_city_id">
                  <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Chrysler</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">GMC</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Infiniti</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Jeep</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Kia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mini</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Porsche</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Subaru</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Volkswagen</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Volvo</a></li>
                 </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but id didn't help either

Comment: I checked again. and it worked. The list is intitially hidden and the autocomplete is working. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked now, accepting your answer. The jquery mobile js inclusion had to be done after the jquery.min.js file inclusion, I was doing it before that. Changing the order of the js file inclusions i.e. first the jquery.min.js and then the jquery.mobile.min.js, solved my problem.